# change the colorbar in healpy.mollview?

Tags: matplotlib, healpy

I know that matplotlib provides many different color bars, and so I wonder if I can replace the default color bar in healpy.mollview with one from matplotlib? In other words, I need to change the color bar in healpy.mollview for some special maps.

Could anyone tell me how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `cmap` argument:

```
from matplotlib import cm
cool_cmap = cm.cool
cool_cmap.set_under("w") # sets background to white
hp.mollview(np.arange(12), cmap=cool_cmap)
```

see the output:
[image: healpy mollview with custom colormap]